# How to access DBFS data from outside the databricks environment using API

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I want to access DBFS data from outside the databricks using API with the help of python code. How can I do that

Comment: Hi @Vineet Sajwan, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no python-specific client to DBFS, as far as I know, though info on the REST API can be found [here](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/dbfs.html), so you can use it inside your python application.

Comment: If I want to access blob storage data using Rest Api instead of DBFS. Is it achievable..?

Comment: Yes, there's a link in my answer to the REST api description.